# Rails not rendering assets in development after deletion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I deleted one **js** and one **scss** file from my **assets** folder and now it's not rendering any asset in development.

I ran into some threads and tried doing **rake assets:clean** and **rake assets:clobber** but none of them worked.

What should I do? What is the normal process of deleting assets?

I'm using Rails 4.2.0

Comment: Is there any error message? Can you just open `localhost:3000/assets/application.css` in browser?

Answer (score 0):

Just create empty `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` and `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` files

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question to be more clear. I actually deleted one js and one scss file. I've still got the application.* there. Thanks for the reply!